# Free particle in Rindler metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, geodesics

I have to discuss the motion of a free particle in Minkowski using the Rindler metric
$$ds^2=e^{2ap}(-d\tau^2+dp^2)$$
So it has to satisfy the geodesic condition $\frac{d^2x^\mu}{d\tau^2}+\Gamma_{\rho\sigma}^\mu=0$
which gives
$$\ddot{p}+2a(\dot{p}^2-\dot{\tau}^2)=0$$
and, because $\tau$ is the proper time (or is prop to it?)
$$\ddot{p}+2a(\dot{p}^2-1)=0$$
$$p=e^{a(1+\sqrt{3})\tau}\quad or \quad p=e^{a(1-\sqrt{3})\tau}$$
so in Rindler coordinates a free particle moves exponentially in time (maybe with a different coefficient instead of $(1+\sqrt{3})$).[Graphic of the motion in Rindler coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K1Nl.jpg).

It's all correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\let\a=\alpha \def\dp{\dot p} \def\dq{\dot q} \def\dx{\dot x}$
No. It isn't true that $\tau$ is proper time. Incidentally, I had
never seen before that form of Rindler metric. It's right, but the
choice of $\tau$ for one coordinate is unfortunate. So let me use $q$
instead:
$$ds^2 = e^{2ap}\,(-dq^2 + dp^2).$$

In a problem like that writing gedesic equations is seldom useful. And
in any case you need *two* equations, as you have two unknown
functions: $p(\tau)$, $q(\tau)$. Usually there are shortcuts, thanks
to symmetries or at least to a general identity:

$$g_{\mu\nu}\,\dx^\mu\,\dx^\nu = -1 \tag1$$
for a timelike geodesic. (Here the dot *does* mean derivative wrt
proper time!)  Did you know eq. (1)? Or can you see why it holds true?

In our case eq. (1) becomes
$$e^{2ap}\,(\dq^2 - \dp^2) = 1.$$

Other useful relations derive from symmetries. Have you heard of it?
Killing vectors? Noether's theorem? At least the special case when one
coordinate does not appear in $g_{\mu\nu}$? This is what happens here:
coefficients of metric tensor don't depend on $q$. If $g_{\mu\nu}$ is
independent of say $x^\a$ then it can be shown that
$g_{\a\nu}\,\dx^\nu$ is constant along any geodesic. In our case
$$e^{2ap}\,\dq = \mathrm{const.} \tag2$$

Of course you could also derive (2) via geodesic equation for $q$.
It's only a longer way.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't think to use conserved charges because, this was an assignment given much before knowing killing vectors, etc. (just geodesics, maybe using both the geodesic for p and $\tau$ the result would be the same). 
Also in the equation between (1) and (2) there is a minus on the right-hand side but i cant edit that

Comment: @Pancio *Also in the equation between (1) and (2) there is a minus on
the right-hand side but i cant edit that* You're right, thank you. It
depends on my being used to a (1,-1,-1,-1) convention. I've edited it.

Comment: @Pancio Of course I suspected you had not seen eq. (1) and Noether's theorem but I wanted to tell you that there are such shortcuts. Moreover, it's true that in principle you could derive those equations from geodesic equations, but it might not be so immediate (I didn't try). Observe that a geodesic equation is second order, whereas my equations are *first integrals*, i.e. first order, containing only $\dot q$ and $\dot p$.